# PHP Router, .htaccess and rewriting query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes

I tried to search for this issue, but haven't found something that solves my problem - I'm almost certain I'm not typing the right searches, as I imagine this has been an issue for others too. If I'm beating a dead horse please point me in the right direction, thank you.

**Existing Code**

I'm building a sort of MVC framework.

*.htaccess* routes all requests to *index.php*.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

```
<?php

require_once "./core/init.php";

Router::create( "./core/router/routes.php" )->direct( Request::uri(), Request::method() );
```

My *router.class.php* file:

```
<?php

class Router {

    protected $routes = array(

        "GET" => array(),

        "POST" => array()

    );

    public static function create( $routes ) {

        $router = new static;

        include $routes;

        return $router;

    }

    public function get( $uri, $controller ) {

        $this->routes[ "GET" ][ $uri ] = $controller;

    }

    public function post( $uri, $controller ) {

        $this->routes[ "POST" ][ $uri ] = $controller;

    }

    public function direct( $uri, $method ) {

        if ( array_key_exists( $uri, $this->routes[ $method ] ) ) {

            include $this->routes[ $method ][ $uri ];

        } else {

            include $this->routes[ "GET" ][ "not-found" ];

        }

    }

}
```

Routes are defined in *routes.php* like so (just the relevant route shown):

```
$router->get( "post", "controllers/get/post.controller.php" );
```

**My Question**

Currently navigating to the below shows the post and the post is retrieved from the database using the slug.

```
/post?p=my-post-name
```

How could I rewrite my router or .htaccess to have the same post shown at the following URL?

```
/post/my-post-name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I solved this by creating a check before the router is directed, not really sure if this is the "right" way.

This basically checks the URI against an array and if the URI contains one of these set values, then it is deconstructed, the last value is stored in a variable called `get` and then the URI is reconstructed minus the fake query string:

```php
// index.php

require_once "./core/init.php";

$uri = Request::uri();

/*
 * Fake query strings
 */
$uriParts = explode( "/", $uri );
$queryPages = array( "post", "category", "edit-post" );

foreach ( $queryPages as $queryPage ) {

    if ( in_array( $queryPage, $uriParts ) ) {

        $get = $uriParts[ count( $uriParts ) - 1 ];
        array_pop( $uriParts );
        $uri = "";

        for ( $i = 0; $i < ( count( $uriParts ) ); $i++ ) {

            $uri .= $uriParts[ $i ] . "/";

        }

        $uri = trim( $uri, "/" );
        break;

    }

}

Router::create( "./core/router/routes.php" )->direct( $uri, Request::method() );
```

The above works with URI's of various depths:

```
post/my-post
category/general
admin/posts/edit-post/my-post
```

The "query string" can be used in controllers with `global $get;` and then used in place of `$_GET`. This would not work for multiple queries but it works perfectly for my requirements.